# How to enable the theme editor cap for an editor role?

Tags: users, user-roles, editor, capabilities

I am trying to add/enable the theme editor for the *editor* role. The *editor* role by default doesn't have the option to manage theme options, so I addded this to functions.php:

```
// get the the role object
$role_object = get_role( 'editor' );

// add $cap capability to this role object
//$role_object->add_cap( 'edit_theme_options' );
$role_object->add_cap( 'manage_options' );
```

But still, I don't see the theme editor option. In the end, I want the theme editor to be the only submenu option.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`edit_themes`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#edit_themes) capability is what allows access to Appearance > Theme Editor:

```
function wpse243341_modify_editor_role() {
    $role = get_role( 'editor' );
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_themes' ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse243341_modify_editor_role');
```

Comment: Just wanted to say Thank You for this code it helped me immediately!